# How to store math expression in c++ list

Tags: c++, data-structures, parsing

I am parsing a infix math expression to a postfix form. I want to store it in a list like `[4.5, 3, 0.25, +, -]` so that I can process it once it's parsed. I could store it in a string again, but I would have to parse it twice. The problem is that I don't know how to store **operators and operands in the same list**. I thought of two children classes of a common parent, but they are totally different.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking how to write code to put "parts of an expression" into a std::list, or are you asking what container would be best suited for your problem? (the former is off-topic here, the latter could be a good question but you'll have to tell us a bit more about what you intend to do with the list after it's constructed)

Comment: Yes what container, or how to put operators/operands in the same data structure. I thought of a list as I am calculating the value given the list in another method.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/

Comment: Well, some kind of tree is the only data structure that makes any sense for the typical use cases, but the answer which says that got downvoted, so I'm highly confused now. Are you more interested in whether to use a class hierarchy or a tagged union or some other mechanism to allow the container to be heterogeneous than you are in what the container itself should be?

Comment: You are saying that you are parsing math expressions. Do you already have something like tokens in it? Could you describe your data structures so far? It seems that you only need heterogeneous containers, which is a well-covered topic; see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/18856824/124319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't know how to store operators and operands in the same list

Consider the [composite design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite):

[image]

The article goes on to show a math expression example:

[image]

This lets you build your own tree.  If you like you can also store all elements in a list but `doThis()` is using the tree to traverse.

What might be a bit confusing is that it shows all the operations as methods.  Instead you could store the operation in the composite node.  Rename `doThis()` to `calculate()` and now you can call `root.calculate()` to compute the whole expression.  You'd be able to do this on any node.  I'd have the interface look like this:

```
<<interface>>
Component
---------  
+calculate()  
+getPrefixString()  
+getInfixString()  
+getPostfixString()  
+addElement(Component component)
```

None of this get's you out of having to reparse elements as you visit each one.  Here's a way to avoid that:

[image]

Now you can do all parsing up front before you construct the tree. `doThis()`, or `calculate()` as I'd rename it, knows which operator to use polymorphically.

Since these all have the same type, `Component`, you are free to store them in a list, array, or whatever.  But the way they link together is still a tree.

You've expressed a construction concern regarding infix notation.  Consider [the builder pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398606&seqNum=5).  It's good at constructing composites.  The link I provided takes you through refactoring just such a case.  I think you'll find enough power that you could deal with infix, prefix, and postfix.

Comment: This is a good approach of what I want to do. This would be so simple to calculate but I'm not sure I would know how to build it from an infix notation.

Comment: A valid concern.  Please see my update.

Comment: Your UML diagrams don't answer the question. My understanding is that OP did not thought of smart pointers, and your answer don't even mention the "pointer" word.

Comment: Ok I think I'm going to do it this way, although the tree won't be balanced at all and will be more like a list. @BasileStarynkevitch he don't even have to mention the "pointer" word, I know how do trees work.

Answer (score 0):

> How to store math expression in c++ list

Consider [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

The fundamental thing here is that prefix, infix, and postfix notations are only ways of presenting math expressions.  When storing you don't have to care how they were presented.  The nifty thing about tree's is that you can translate equivalent expressions in these notations into identical tree's.  And you can convert the tree to any of these notations.

Here's the same tree, traversed the same way each time.  The difference is when you pick up the value from the node.  The difference is the dot.  When you touch the dot you pick up (or put down) the letter.  By rotating the dot you get the characters in the three different notations.

[image]
Prefix : pre-order traversal

[image]
Infix : in-order traversal

[image]
Postfix : post order traversal

There is a c++ data structure that works well for this.  It's called [btrees](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html)

Comment: postfix expressions could be seen as a bytecode for a stack VM, and then you don't want to represent them as trees but as lists. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I think CandiedOrange's answer is a better approach as trees are much more useful for performing operations on expressions, if all you want to do is store it and later evaluate it, a postfix list along with a stack-based evaluatir is adequate and simpler.

When you say that there is nothing in common between your operands and operators, that's not entirely true. In order to execute your expression, you'll need to visit each of them in order, providing a stack for them to work with. Operands will push a value on the stack, while operators will pop a pair of values, perform a calculation, and push the result.  Both can have the same interface: They are *stack operations*.

Comment: What methods do you suggest the class (which can be operator or operand) would have?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I assume and hope that you want to code in *genuine* [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) using its [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) & [utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility) library; don't use an earlier variant of C++; be sure to have a *recent* compiler: in june 2016, use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) version [5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) or [6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) and/or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) version [3.7 or 3.8](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html), both being [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software))</sup>

You probably want to represent the [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) of your parsed expressions. Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). You might want to read the first chapters of the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition). Or code a simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Or use some parser generator (often incorrectly called [compiler-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler)) like [ANTLR3](http://www.antlr3.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) -or some [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)-). BTW your problem is similar to one of the examples given in `bison` documentation ([infix calc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html)).

You won't organize your AST as a C++ *list*, but as a *tree*. For example, you might have a common (abstract) superclass `class expr` and have an abstract subclass for leaves `class leaf_expr: public class expr` with concrete final subclasses like `class int_expr: public leaf_expr` for integer literals (e.g. `12`), `class var_expr: public leaf_expr` for variables (e.g. `x`). You'll have a superclass `class binary_expr : class_expr` for binary nodes -containing [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) fields (probably `std::shared_ptr<expr>`...) for left and right sub-trees- with concrete final subclasses `class sum_expr : public class binary_expr` etc for sum nodes (e.g. for `x+12`).

If you need to get a postfix translation of your AST, you'll define *another* representation for postfix expressions, perhaps as a list of smart pointers to postfix components, and you define another class hierarchy for your postfix components: an abstract superclass `class postfix` with various subclasses `class int_postfix` (for a postfix integer literal operand like `12`), `class var_postfix` (for a postfix variable operand like `x`), `class plus_postfix` (for a postfix operator like `+`), using some intermediate abstract superclasses like `class operand_postfix : public postfix` for operands and `class operator_postfix : public postfix` and probably `class unary_operator_postfix : public operator_postfix` and `class binary_operator_postfix : public operator_postfix` etc...) ... and have a list of smart pointers of these (e.g. `std::list<std::unique_ptr<postfix>>` ...). Then you easily can code a transformer from AST to postfix list :

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<postfix>> transform_ast_to_postfix
    (std::shared_ptr<expr>);
```

---

> The problem is that I don't know how to store operators and operands in the same list

You'll have a list of smart pointers to a common super-class, e.g. `std::list<std::unique_ptr<postfix>>`. In some cases (but not in yours) you could also consider having a list of objects containing a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). FWIW [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) will give you [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

<sup>(You might avoid *explicitly* representing AST in memory, and directly build the list of smart pointers to `postfix` elements in actions of your parser, but I believe that building the AST is easier and more general)</sup>

---

Notice that **a good understanding of [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) is *essential***. Using smart pointers instead of raw pointers (e.g. `expr*`) could help you write cleaner code and avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You should understand [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and probably (in C++11) the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) question.

You should read Stroustrup's [Programming - Principles & practice using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Answer (score -1):

If the expression is already converted to RPN / postfix, you just need a basic vector or array.  Create a simple data structure that holds both values and operator info, and push each item onto the list.

```
struct myToken {
   int tokType;  //1 = value, 2 = operator
   float tokVal;
   int opType; //1 = add, 2 = sub, 3 = mult, etc
}
```

To re-evaluate the expression you just iterate the list.  You can also extend this to support function calls such as sum() sqrt() by adding members to track a function name and the number of required parameters, and having your expression evaluator check for them.

Comment: This is C like code, not genuine C++; and even in C you'll better use tagged unions in such cases.

Comment: Also, even in C the `tokType` should be some `enum` !

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This is programmers (whiteboard), not Stack (code).  The snippet above was for illustration purposes.  Implementation is up to the OP.