# Design Patterns for an expression project

Tags: design-patterns

I have the implemented a calculator that is very similar to the following UML diagram. The only new thing is a new class, a Recognizer class, that says if the expression is written correctly or not.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxYa5.jpg]

I have applied a factory design pattern for the operations Add,Sub,Extract,Division but I'm  also interested in applying a structural pattern aswell(Adapter,Bridge,Filter,Composite,Decorator,Facade,Flyweight or Proxy). What would fit the diagram?

Comment: You're looking at it backward. Design patterns are not building blocks, you can't design an architecture by trying to fit as many design patterns as you can.

Comment: @VincentSavard I understand this, however it's for a project where I'm asked to add a structural pattern, alongside a creational and behaviour pattern. So I'm pretty much trying to get the best thing that can fit inside this, even if it looks horrible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are obliged to chose a structural pattern, I'd suggest to revisit the `Expression` and its derivates with the [Composite pattern](https://www.google.be/amp/s/www.oodesign.com/amp/composite-pattern/):

- every expression can be composed themselves of sub-expressions
- some expressions can be binary (e.g. those that you already identified)
- some expressions can be leafs (e.g. a variable or a constant literal used in an expression)

For this to work, you need to refactor evaluate to take no argument (or a map  of variables with their values as argument).

**Edit:**  [this article](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) has a nice (although simplified) example of a composite used for expressions.  This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/321907/209774) about expressions data structures has some answer using the composite pattern.